# Generate CERT.RSA for an APK without jarsigner / apksigner or any java tool

Tags: android, ssl, apk, jarsigner, apksigner

I'm currently trying to package APK on the fly using this process :

- When the enduser asks for the download, I add a file in the APK
- I sign the APK (it's the same key that is used all along)
- I deliver the APK

The issue is that signing the APK with common tools (apksigner, jarsigner) can be time consuming for big APK (500M +)

My goal is to update the META-INF data and only generate the new CERT.RSA file (which is an encoding of CERT.SF if I'm not mistaken)

I have successfully found how to generate MANIFEST.MF and CERT.SF in the META-INF directory. I just can't find the algorithm, or any openssl command to generate the CERT.RSA from the CERT.SF.

Any clue ?

Comment: Did that answer help?

Answer (score 0):

First off, make sure that your `minSdkVersion` < 24. If you have 24 or above, then these files are not necessary and you can sign only with [APK Signature v2 scheme](https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/v2) using `apksig`, which is going to be an order of magnitude faster to sign.

Now, assuming that you *do* need v1 signing and want to generate it manually, I would recommend that you look at the OpenJDK implementation of **JarSigner**. See in particular the `Block` class: https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/security/tools/JarSigner.java#L2221-L2344

This is the content of the *.RSA file. As you can see, it's the signature of a combination of a few things. If you're only using an RSA key, you can probably simplify this code quite a bit and adapt it for your tool.